# C++: Do functions within structs get copied with the struct?

Tags: c++, function, struct

In a struct (or class), I know that I can add a function and then call it later.

```cpp
struct State {
    int turnsLeft;
    void nextTurn() {
        turnsLeft--;
    }
};
State s1{1};
State s2{2};
s1.nextTurn();
```

My question is, how do these functions relate to how much space the struct takes up? I know a int is 4 bytes and so creating s1 and s2 costs at least 4*2=8 bytes. But, will a new copy of this function be created each time that I make a new struct, or will only one copy of the function be made and shared no matter how many different `State` functions I make? If the function is copied each time, how can I write the code so that only one copy of the function is made? A static function doesn't work very naturally, since I want to access `this` when I modify `turnsLeft`.

Comment: I don't know any compiler that would store functions as part of the struct itself - they are pretty much always stored elsewhere

Comment: @3Dave "Each instance of the class contains a VMT" No they don't. Only polymorphic classes have virtual tables.

Comment: @3Dave Only classes with `virtual` methods have "virtual method tables".  Most classes don't have a VMT.

Comment: First off, only virtual functions cause VMTs to exist on most implementations.  Secondly, virtual function call overhead is real and not just a nanosecond issue.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 Yes it's real, and not just a nanosecond issue. It's also something that you only worry about when you are trying to suck the last few *femtoseconds* out of a loop. iOS app developers will never worry about VMTs

Comment: @3Dave Why in the world would non virtual classes have a method table? They can do static dispatch, completely bypassing all need for one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose I need to start with a disclaimer: what I say below applies to all known implementations. In theory somebody could to things differently (but in this case it's so unlikely that it's hardly worth considering even as an intellectual exercise).

Member functions will only affect the size of the class in one way: if the class contains at least one virtual function, the size of the class will increase by the size of one pointer (usually called the vtable pointer). Even if the class doesn't directly define any virtual functions, if it inherits from a base class that declares at least on virtual function, it will have a vtable pointer for that class. If it inherits from multiple base classes, it will normally contain a vtable pointer for each base class that declares at least one virtual function. Using `virtual` inheritance can reduce that in a few specific cases.

But no, an object of a class doesn't normally "contain" actual copies of the function(s) of that class, so the size, complexity or number of normal member functions won't affect the size or time taken to copy an object of that class. Virtual functions can have some effect, but it's still usually pretty minimal.

Member functions do affect one other thing a bit though: non-static member functions have access to the data in the object on which they're invoked. Inside the member function, a pointer to that object is visible as `this`. In most implementations, even though it's not a visible parameter, `this` is actually passed as a parameter, so if you look at the generated code, it will contain an instruction or two to load `this` into some known location before the call is made. But this only affects the size of code *calling* a member function, not the size of the object of that class.

Comment: It's a sad, sad world when we need to add such a disclaimer. Like, my optics simulator accounts for Ex, Ey, Ez, Hx, Hy, and Hz, but who knows: we might find ourselves with a new field or a new dimension tomorrow. Well-written and helpful answer.

Comment: @3Dave: Actually, I think there are some good points to it. The reason it's needed is that C++ is an open standard that anybody can implement in any way they see fit, as long as they meet its requirements on visible behavior. On some future system, it's barely possible that it would even make sense to include code for member functions in an object, even though it seems ridiculous to us right here/now. But even if it remains insane, the freedom for people to do as they see fit remains valuable.

Comment: I understood the disclaimer and the reason for it. But, wouldn't it be nice if we added a disclaimer for the edge case rather than the general case? (Former ARM staff engineer, now a GPU guy elsewhere. I get what you're saying and agree.)

Comment: Arguably, it's impossible to use memory for member functions due to standard layout, common initial sequence and so on.